# List<Label> throwing Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. error

Tags: c#, list

Hate to ask this but where am I going wrong?

```
public void foo(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Label> exerciseLabels = new List<Label>();

    string tempExercise = exerciseTextBox.Text;
    int numExercises = 0;
    day[tempDay].addExercise(numExercises, tempExercise);

    exerciseLabels.Add(new Label());
    exerciseLabels[1].Text = string.Format("{0}. {1}", numExercises + 1, tempExercise);

}
```

I am receiving an argument is out range.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<Label> exerciseLabels = new List<Label>();
...
exerciseLabels.Add(new Label());
exerciseLabels[1].Text = ...
```

lists are 0-based; should be `exerciseLabels[0]` for the first item. Or better still:

```
var label = new Label();
label.Text = ...
exerciseLabels.Add(label);
```

no need to access the indexer.